# Save date from HTML type="datetime-local" to firebird database

Tags: html, date, firebird

I an capturing date with this HTML code

```
Start Time <br>
<input  **strong text**name="start_time" type="datetime-local" id="id_start_time" onchange="Fenable('id_end_time,id_closed')" ><br>
End Time <br>
```

I an using firebird

I get error while saving the record to the database

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: -303 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code
>   = -303 conversion error from string "2018-09-28T20:20"

how to convert the input into a legal string ?
Can any one help ?

Comment: added html tag, removed irrelevant php tag, indented given "html" code and inserted error into a blockquote

Comment: can you add your javascript for the onchange function? Your markup for the HTML is not valid. Use <strong></strong> tags, and remember to close your tags .

Comment: Please show the actual code used to insert.

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/php

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.
I solved it by using following javascript code

 var str = document.getElementById("id_start_time").value; 
var s_time = str.replace("T", " ");

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates you are attempting to insert a string to a `TIMESTAMP` column, and that string is not formatted as expected by Firebird. Firebird supports a number of string formats, but none of them include the `T`.

Make sure that the value you insert is of the form `2018-09-28 20:20` (format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm[:ss[.fffff]]`), or that you are inserting a suitable timestamp datatype.

BTW: The error also suggests that you are using string concatenation to create the query instead of a parameterized query. Concatenating your query string is unsafe as it leaves your open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Rotteveel -Thanks for suggestion.
Iam using  bindParam method to  save data.

I solved it by using following javascript code

```
function clk_submit(){
//document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "inline";
```

***var str = document.getElementById("id_start_time").value;

 var s_time = str.replace("T", " ");***

```
 var str = document.getElementById("id_end_time").value; 
var e_time = str.replace("T", " ");

    var xdata = {
    bpr_pid:document.getElementById("id_product_id").value,
    bpr_bno:document.getElementById("id_batch_no").value,
    bpr_stageid:document.getElementById("id_stage").value,
    bpr_cpid:"0",
    bpr_bwt:document.getElementById("id_batch_weight").value,
    bpr_status_id:"0",
```

**bpr_stime:s_time,**

```
    bpr_etime:e_time,
    bpr_closed:document.getElementById("id_closed").value,
    bpr_uid:"<?php echo $_SESSION["userid"] ?>",                                
    bpr_rem:"",
    bpr_inbid:"0",
    bpr_fcid:document.getElementById("id_formula_code").value,
    bpr_seq_code_id:document.getElementById("id_sequence_code").value
    };

        var myJSON = JSON.stringify(xdata);
        var   xmlhttp;
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    //              document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
                    if (this.responseText==1) {
                        alert( "Record Saved Successfully");
                    } else {
                            alert(this.responseText);
                        }
                }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "json_save_to_db.php", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("x=" + myJSON);
    }
```

It perfect now.